# In a CQRS why should the command side feature a Repository.FindById(id) method?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, cqrs

I have been reading a ton about CQRS and understand the basic idea of separating command (write) and query (read) operations.

On the other hand, I have seen a few times where a `Repository<T>` on the command side features a FindById(id) method. 
Example:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
  void Save(T aggregate); //for add and update
  void FindById(int id);
  //no delete!
}
```

**Why is that, and why would you need a FindByID method there?**
Does it maybe have to do with checking concurrency?

Comment: Well maybe you could link to the tutorial that uses CQRS and repository patterns together, so we can interpret and explain it to you? As currently stated, it's pretty unanswerable.

Comment: @John you can bring this question to DDD/CQRS google group here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddcqrs

Comment: @codeCaster it's in the book Architecting Applications for the Enterprise

Answer (score 3):

A very simple example, using a BlogPost that a user can give a Score:

```
public class LikeBlogPostCommand
{
    public int BlogPostId { get; private set; }
    public int Score { get; private set; }

    public LikeBlogPostCommand(int blogPostId, int score)
    {
        BlogPostId = blogPostId;
        Score = score;
    }
}
```

And the handler that contains the business logic, which uses the repository to apply the command:

```
public class BlogCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<LikeBlogPostCommand>
{
    // Injection not shown
    private IRepository<BlogPost> _repository;

    public void HandleCommand(LikeBlogPostCommand command)
    {
        var blogPost = _repository.FindById(command.BlogPostId);
        blogPost.AddRating(command.Score);
        _repository.Save();     
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a method to get aggregate from database. FindById serve for this. When you follow cqrs pattern typically you have command that get id of aggregate in signature method. The in method you get from database this aggregate entity by id and use one or more of its methods. After that you save aggregate back to database. So repository have method to get entity aggregate from db and method to save it to db.

PS: Query is not read operations. It is query operations: it usually returns plain models instead of aggregate.